# Userlocation updated to wifi every 10 seconds

Tags: iphone, gps, cllocationmanager

I am trying to updated the userlocation every 10 secs from my code. But when I move from wifi to 3G then I face an issue. The every alternate request goes from the location where my wifi is located. What can be done?

Here is my code

NSNumber *n1;
        NSNumber *n2;

```
    if([ud boolForKey:@"applicationActive"])
    {

        n1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[map.userLocation coordinate].latitude];
        n2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[map.userLocation coordinate].longitude];
    }
    else
    {
        CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        n1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
        n2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }


    [dict setObject:[ud objectForKey:@"CurrentDriverID"] forKey:@"DriverId"];
    [dict setObject:[n1 stringValue] forKey:@"Latitude"];
    [dict setObject:[n2 stringValue] forKey:@"Longitude"];

    [requestG SaveDriverlocationWS:dict delegate:self];
```

NOTE: The application stays in foreground when this happens. The SaveDriverlocationWS method saves the current location to the server

Comment: http://www.macrumors.com/2012/08/09/ios-6-beta-adds-wi-fi-plus-cellular-option-to-increase-data-reliability/. iOS 6, you gotta love its new function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be setting an accuracy level for your location manager - I would try this and see if things improve. It looks from your code like you might be writing an app for drivers, in which case you may want to use the `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` accuracy level (if you, you should use another more appropriate level, since the `BestForNavigation` filter uses up *a lot* of power and is designed for situations where the phone is in a car dock and powered).

Comment: This happens even if I am a few miles away from the wifi network I started from. Not sure if accuracy is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding. using Wifi or 3G is system level setting. CLLocationManager uses current system's network to get device's location, while programmer has nowhere to switch network between 3G/Wifi.

Comment: Yes, my question is that when I move away from my wifi and the phone swithces to 3G automatically, then it starts alternating between the current location and the location of wifi where I started from. Any idea what should be done? thanks

Comment: your mean there is an outstanding difference between the last wifi location and the new 3G location?

Comment: yes.. I start the app from a wifi location.. but as I move away from wifi the phone swithces to 3g and the problem starts..